# Icon to convey "New," to be placed next to new features in a web-based app. Any successful precedents/examples?

Tags: icons, new-experience

I am needing to create an icon to flag new features in our site (such as proprietary search filters, to start). We'd like this to be consistent and recognizable for all kinds of new feature roll-outs in the UI). It will need to perform at standard 16x16px scale in some contexts. Have not had much luck in finding a good precedent for this. Product manager's 1st thought was a little star burst, but at small scale without a message, that feels a bit vague. A "plus" sign is misleading. Trumpet/horn is more tied to notifications about new products (Evernote). Leaves (new growth), stars (variation on the burst) — none of these have clean and straightforward connotations.

Open to any experiences out there with this type of requirement.

Comment: Are you asking for an icon suggestion?

Comment: Would a link with a notification badge (to a page with all the latest updates on) suffice?

Comment: This page was the most helpful in explaining intended logic behind the initial closure: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/.

This closure still feels like the result of a misunderstanding of my question's intent, but the page above (which I had to dig for myself in the course of my puzzlement) at least helps me know how to craft the next one to sidestep SO alarms.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an easy problem to solve, but it tends to be much more complex than just sticking an icon next to a new feature.  You run into questions like:

- when does xyz widget cease to be new?
- for first time users who have never visited the site/app before, is it necessary to announce "new" functionality?  It's ALL new to them.
- how many "new" stickers will you allow on a screen?  Can the icon count for a whole new page, or just a facet of the page?
- what size of enhancement qualifies for an announcement vs. a silent release?
- who will police the "new" stickers and remove them when needed?

Because of the maintenance nightmare implied above, it is typically frowned upon to announce new features inline, on a page-by-page or feature-by-feature basis.

Instead, here are some suggestions for doing this cleanly are:

- consolidate your "new feature" announcements in one location (overlay on startup, load of app, or on an external page that can be updated independently, accessed via a "what's new" link)
- initiate other channels of communication to announce what's new (perhaps a pre-release email to users)

In the end, unless you have a *remarkably* small and simple product, using the icon-per-new-feature approach does not scale and creates a slippery slope that could result in competing stickers across the product. My experience is that this band-aid will create more problems in the long run than opting not to make any announcements at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a combination of icon and text. For example:

[image: New]

By combining text and icons you can convey the message you want and include an icon that best represents what you would like it to look like. So even though the icon alone may not clearly display the connotation by adding some stylish text you can make it straightforward. Just an idea, hope it helps.

Comment: I'm all for the gleaming effect, but that one's a bit glaring.  For small icons a smaller version of this in yellow/gold on a corner, perhaps with a subtle animated swiping sheen to draw attention to the "*"

Answer (score 0):

The problem with just an icon for new features is that if the user doesn't normally use that particular section, they wouldn't necessarily know about it.
also how do you decide when to hide a particular new icon?

- after the user has seen it (might get cumbersome to track all new
  changes)
- after some time has passed (might miss some of the changes
  because the user is away)

A better solution to new features/ui changes is to do something like google does when they roll new interface changes: interactive overlay with some kind of highlight on the new elements.

This way even the users understand better what the new feature does and if they're not interested they can skip the introduction overlay. It also makes it easier for you to introduce complex functionality.

Comment: This question was part of a much larger workflow I was planning. It was a semiotic question; now resolved. Thanks for your response(s) all.